# JS How to correct my Date Time Script?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript Caspio

I am trying to make sure the time in entered is less than the time out entered.  I was determined to figure this out on my own but just can get go any further without help. Here is my code. Since Defined_Date_Out is required, I thought replacing the users erroneous entry with null would prevent the submission from being initiated.  Thanks for any advise ?

```
<div id="datefix">
<script>
function DateCheck()
 {

var dateout = document.getElementById('Defined_Time_Out').value;
var datein = document.getElementById('Defined_Time_In').value;

if (dateout <=  datein)

alert("Please enter a date and time OUT after date and time IN ");

document.getElementById("InsertRecordDefined_Time_Out").value = null;
}

document.getElementById('InsertRecordDefined_Time_Out').onChange = DateCheck;

</script>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code (HTML and CSS) so that we can replicate your issue and show you a working result. You also make reference to a "submission" needing to be prevented, so you need to show that code as well.

Answer (score 0):

"null" in > and < comparison operations will performs type coercion and convert to 0. I suggest you can do a input validation before comparison.